# bash - opening an image only when a corresponding text file exists

Tags: linux, bash

I came across a problem in Bash when I would try to only open images based upon the information stored in .txt files about them. I am trying to sort a number of images by size or height, and display an image with them in the sorted order, but if there exists a .jpg in the folder without a .txt file with the same name, it should not process it.

I have the sorting piece of my situation done, and am trying to figure out how I would go about opening only the images that have a .jpg extension WITH a .txt file.

I figured a solution would look like me putting every .jpg's name (without extension) in a list and then process through the list and run something like:

[if -f $filename.txt ]; then ~~~

but I came across the problem of iterating through without a for-loop, or else all the pictures would open multiple times. My attempt was:

```
for i in *jpg; do
y=$y ${i.jpg}
done
if[ -f $y.txt ] then
(sorting parts)
```

This only looked at the last filename in y, as it should, but I am trying to figure out a way to look at each separate filename and see if there exists that textfile, in order to include it in the sorting.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: have you tried something like using the and `&&` operator in your `if` statement?

Comment: @user556068 yes, to see if the name and .txt both exist as files, but I am not sure how to go about processing each in the list rather than just the last. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Could you clarify the question, it's not clear what do you want, it might be a good idea to add that sorting you v mentioned. You have shown a way to check a file existence which is a solution to the question in headline.

Answer (score 1):

Collecting a list of file names in a single variable is an antipattern.  You want to collect them in an array instead.

```
a=()
for f in *.jpg; do
    if [ -e "${f%.jpg}".txt ]; then
        continue
    fi
    a+=("$f")
done
# now do things with "${a[@]}"
```

Frequently, you don't really need to collect the files in an array -- just do everything you were doing inside the `for` loop to each individual file as you traverse the files.

(And actually `y=$y ${i%.jpg}` doesn't append to `y` -- it sets `y` to itself for the duration of attempting to execute a file named `i` sans the `.jpg` extension, which would most likely fail in the vast majority of cases.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the file check first such that find just reports files that have a corresponding text file. The following snippet will just display `jpg` files that have a corresponding `txt` file:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -maxdepth 1 -exec /bin/bash -c '[ -e "${0%.*}.txt" ] && echo "$0";' {} \;
```

Comment: That looks like a massive [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo). If you get rid of the outer `echo` and the command substitution, you can also get rid of the `grep` which will no longer be necessary or useful.

Comment: @tripleee: yes, you are right -- I changed the code snippet above.

Comment: `find` will traverse subdirectories, too, which was not mentioned in the requirements. Maybe add `-maxdepth 1` to disable that, and perhaps remove the superfluous wildcard.